# Adding multiple columns in a table such as using a for / while loop in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to create a child table using Flask-SQLAlchemy that holds around 600 columns.
Each column is supposed to be a different hobby with a boolean value of true or false (whether or not he has this hobby).
However I do have an issue. Using Flask-SQLAlchemy's Model to create it seems problematic since I will have to write each field myself.
i.e:

```py
class hobbies(database.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
   hobby1 = db.Column(db.Boolean)
   hobby2 = db.Column(db.Boolean)
   hobby3 = db.Column(db.Boolean)
   ....
   ....
   hobby600 = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

(database stands for the variable that holds - database = SQLAlchemy(app))

Is there a way such as using a for or a while loop to add all of the columns to the table?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bad table design(no offence), instead of this you can create table as given below

```py
class Hobbies(database.Model):
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   hobby = db.Column(db.String(50))

class UserHobbies(database.Model):
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'),primary_key=True)
   hobbie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('hobbies.id'),primary_key=True)
```

Instead of creating 600 columns in hobbies table just create 600 rows and create another table UserHobbies for many to many relationship with users and hobbies.
You can also utilize `bulk_insert_mappings(ModelName,list_data)` function for inserting bulk data in to hobbies table.

Comment: I have a related question regarding many to many relationship like your solution. If I have a similar thing I want to save per person as well as compare between users for example if they like basketball, soccer and hockey (3 Boolean collumns). Is it better to make a many to many relationship like your solution or since it's only 3 fields I can just add them as columns in the user's table?

Comment: From my research the more standard ways is creating many to many  relationship.But in this case I prefer creating three columns for each hobbies like you since its only three fields.